# Custom themes and colors in android

Tags: android, colors, styles, themes

Can i define two completely different colors.xml for two different themes? For example in my case we use much more different colors in pallette that defined in theme by standart(android:colorPrimary, android:colorAccent, android:colorBackground etc). Hope, that my question is clear. If it's not, ask me in comments, please.

Comment: you can create different theme for different activities

Comment: if you want to support multiple Themes in your application,You have to declare suitable attributes against each theme and then define styles for each attribute.Afterwards you can invoke activity's method setTheme to set actual theme.

Comment: It is not possible to create dynamic color.xml. But you can create different resource files with different name.And you can use these color resource files as input colors to your theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after searching a bit I found a solution like this. Designer doesn't want to use colorPrimary etc, so I add my custom attribute in attrs like this :

`<attr name="colorExperiment" format="color"/>`

After this I add this attr in styles in theme like this:

```
 <style name="DarkTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/onyx</item>
    <item name="colorExperiment">@color/onyx</item>
</style>
```

And use in layout for example:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/auth_caption"
   android:includeFontPadding="false"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:textSize="34dp"
   android:text="@string/auth_caption"
   android:textColor="?colorExperiment"
 />
```